# jQuery click function not working with Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am loading a InfoBox on a google map when an element on the map is clicked. The content inside the info window is loaded asynchronously with jQuery

I am trying to recognize when one of the elements inside the ajax loaded content is clicked (using jQuery) but I can't get jQuery to recognize the click event.

I have tried using a **live** click event but it is still not being recognized:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ajax-trigger-add-to-watchlist').live("click", function(){
        alert('1');
    });
});
```

I am guessing this is just some weird behavior with the google maps API. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the HTML?  Which version of jQuery?... `.live()` has been deprecated since version 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what was going on with the jQuery part, but I solved the problem by using an `onclick` inline call on the trigger element

Comment: I tried the same, but how dod you manage to retrieve the element ? `$(this)` doesn't select the element that has been clicked if the function is called with the attribute `onclick`.

Comment: You could pass a reference to the element as an argument in the function called by the `onclick`, eg: `onclick="myFunction(referenceToElement)"`